# I can not run show databases; command on terminal for hive

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, metadata, hql

When I write

```
> show databases;
```

in Hive, I get the following error;

```
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

Can you please provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command sub hive directory;

```
bin/schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
```

So, make sure the services are started;

```
start-all.sh
```

this command run.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the default setting:/**user/hive/warehouse**  (in the hive-site.xml) is not properly created or permission granted. (**pls note this is **user**, not **usr**)

which may be the culprit if you are doing a manual setup!

1) You may first check out the hive-site.xml (located at $HIVE_HOME/conf in my case is /usr/local/hive/conf) if you want, but which is the initially set default anyway

2) check if the path in Hadoop using:   *hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse*  exists or not?

3) create the Hadoop folder by using: *hadoop fs -mkdir /usr/hive/wawrehouse* if non-existing, take a look at the access right using  Hadoop fs -ls ...............

4) use *Hadoop fs -chmod g+w /usr/.................*  to grant the needed right

Either the user vs usr, or the set up of the warehouse, could be common causes

**Reference** (from hive-site.xml):

```
<property>
   <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
   <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
   <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>
```

Note: you also have to make sure another Hadoop folder /tmp is also properly set as above